# Can't make the items in a ListBox align correctly using TabStops

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, listbox

I have the following problem with ListbBox.

To make it easy to understand I have simplified it a bit.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("xxxxxx" +"\t\t\t"+ "yyyyyyy");
        listBox1.Items.Add("xxxxxxx" + "\t\t\t" + "yyyyyyy");
        listBox1.Items.Add("xxxxxxxx" + "\t\t\t" + "yyyyyyy");
        listBox1.Items.Add("xxxxxxxxx" + "\t\t\t" + "yyyyyyy");
        listBox1.Items.Add("xxxxxxxxxx" + "\t\t\t" + "yyyyyyy");
    }
}
```

From row 1 to 4 it prints out perfectly in straight rows downwards. But the 5th row is completly off when I run the program, although there is plenty of space.  Can any body help me to get all items to be in straight rows downwards?

Comment: Would this even line up with fixed-width characters? Ie in a Console app? I don't think so. That is not how `\t` works.

Comment: Your answer will come from the [ListBox.DrawItem Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem?view=netframework-4.8), but you won't like it.

Comment: The ListBox has no tab positions defined nor do most other controls, except controls like RichTextBox. An alternative option is to use a DataGridView or a ListView with two columns, but often is just easier to work with `DrawItem` as @HenkHolterman said.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - I seem to faintly remember that the ListBox _does_ support tabs. But that isn't enough for the OP's problem.

Comment: You should use Steve's answer; other than that you need to know the size of a tab and use the right number of tabs to align. Usually tabs are 4 characters so it is not unexpected for the 5th line to fail..

Answer (score 4):

You need to set  the property [CustomTabOffsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.customtaboffsets?view=netframework-4.8) and the property [UseCustomTabOffsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usecustomtaboffsets?view=netframework-4.8) and then you can reduce the number of tabs in your strings to only one.

For example

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.Size = new Size(500, 200);
lb.CustomTabOffsets.Add(100);
lb.UseCustomTabOffsets = true;

lb.Items.Add("xxxxxx" + "\t" + "yyyyyyy");
lb.Items.Add("xxxxxxx" + "\t" + "yyyyyyy");
lb.Items.Add("xxxxxxxx" + "\t" + "yyyyyyy");
lb.Items.Add("xxxxxxxxx" + "\t" + "yyyyyyy");
lb.Items.Add("xxxxxxxxxx" + "\t" + "yyyyyyy");

Form f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(lb);
f.Show();
```

Of course you should change that 100 to something more consistent with the actual maximum length of the first part of your strings and the width of your ListBox

Answer (score 2):

The standard ListBox supports Tab Stops (it's created using the [LBS_USETABSTOPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-box-styles) style), but custom Tab Stop must be enabled setting [`UseCustomTabOffsets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usecustomtaboffsets)`= true`, then adding one or more values, representing the Tab positions, to the [CustomTabOffsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.customtaboffsets) [IntegerCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.integercollection).

There's a catch in calculating these *positions*; as described in Docs about the [LB_SETTABSTOPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lb-settabstops) message:

> (...) the integers represent the number of quarters of the average character
>   width for the font that is selected into the list box. For example, a
>   tab stop of 4 is placed at 1.0 character units, and a tab stop of 6 is
>   placed at 1.5 average character units. However, if the list box is
>   part of a dialog box, the integers are in dialog template units. The
>   tab stops must be sorted in ascending order (...)

Since [Font.ToLogFont()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.tologfont) doesn't return the average size of a character in the `lfWidth` member of the [LOGFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfontw) structure, we can calculate it (without PInvoking) from pixels measures as:

```
([CurrentTextWidth] / [AverageCharWidth]) * [TabSize]
```

Where **`[CurrentTextWidth]`** is the width in pixels of a string, calculated using [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext),
the **`[AverageCharWidth]`** can be calculated measuring the difference between `M` and `i`,
and **`[TabSize]`** represent the quarters of the average char width (as described in the Docs, a TabStop of `4` is equal to the width of the average char, in relation to the Font currently selected).

Sample test, to create 3 columns from text parts separated by **`'\t'`** in a ListBox:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] {
    "x\tyyyyyyy\teeeeee",
    "xxxx\tyyyyyyy\tmmmmmmm",
    "xxxxxx\tyyyyyyy\tlllllll",
    "AbcdEfgHilm\tyyyyyyy\tgggggggg",
    "xxxxxx\tyyyyyyy\tzzzzzzz",
    "XXaaMMiixxx\tyyyyyyy\tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
});
SetListBoxTabs(listBox1);
```

Here, I'm setting `float tabSize = 4.2f` instead of `4.0`, because there must be some space between the text parts separated by a Tab, so I'm adding a fraction of the base value to create some space between Columns.
This value can then be used to proportionally adjust the space between columns.

```
public void SetListBoxTabs(ListBox listBox)
{
    float tabSize = 4.2f;
    float currTabStop = 0;

    int tabs = listBox.GetItemText(listBox.Items[0]).Split('\t').Length - 1;
    if (tabs == 0) return;
    var tabStops = new List<int>(tabs);
    tabStops.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, tabs).ToArray());

    using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(listBox.Handle))
    {
        float average = GetFontAverageCharSize(g, listBox.Font);

        foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
        {
            string text = listBox.GetItemText(item);
            string[] parts = text.Split('\t');  // Use Substring(IndexOf()) here
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                float width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, parts[i], listBox.Font,
                    Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding).Width;
                float tabWidth = (width / average) * tabSize;
                currTabStop += tabWidth;
                tabStops[i] = (int)Math.Max(currTabStop, tabStops[i]);
            }
            currTabStop = 0;
        }
    }

    listBox.UseTabStops = true;  // Just in case 1 ...
    listBox.UseCustomTabOffsets = true;
    var offsets = listBox.CustomTabOffsets;
    offsets.Clear(); // Just in case 2 ...
    foreach (int tab in tabStops) { offsets.Add(tab); }
}

public float GetFontAverageCharSize(Graphics g, Font font)
{
    string textMax = new string('M', 100);
    string textMin = new string('i', 100);
    float maxWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, textMax, listBox1.Font).Width;
    float minWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, textMin, listBox1.Font).Width;
    return (maxWidth + minWidth) / (2.0f * textMax.Length);
}
```