# Formating In Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

```
 lstPrint.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-20} {1,5}", "Denomination", "Count"))

        For x As Integer = 0 To 6
            lstPrint.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-20} {1,13:S}", ouputArray(x), "Count"))
        Next
```

For the sake of making things easier, `Dim outputArray As String() = {"1$", "2$", "5$", "10$", "20$", "50$", "100$"}`, and I swapped the second array and made it just say Count.

[image]

typically I would simply use `Convert.ToChar(Keys.Tab)` to make all my columns line up, but I'm trying to get better with string formatting. How would I go about compensating for the difference in characters?

Comment: You *could* use the [CustomTabOffsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.customtaboffsets) feature, also enabling `UseCustomTabOffsets`, to create Tab Stops based on pixel positions, as shown here: [Can't make the items in a ListBox align correctly using TabStops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56826174/7444103). If you have just one TabStop, use Steve's answer. Mine deals with more than one. BUT, as noted in the answer here, it's probably better to replace the ListBox with a ListView (so you have *real* Columns), if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a fixed-width font if you expect that sort of formatting to produce aligned text. Spaces are much narrower than other characters in variable-width fonts.

Otherwise, how about using a control that actually has columns instead of a `ListBox`, e.g. `ListView` or `DataGridView`? Using the best tool for the job is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I set the font for the list box to a fixed width font. Next I got the length of the longest string in the array. I used .PadLeft to make all the strings the same length.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    ListBox1.Font = New Font("Consolas", 12)
    Dim outputArray As String() = {"1$", "2$", "5$", "10$", "20$", "50$", "100$"}
    Dim longest As Integer = outputArray.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Length).FirstOrDefault().Length
    For Each s In outputArray
        ListBox1.Items.Add(s.PadLeft(longest) & "    Count")
    Next
End Sub
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Interesting, so I had Font("Times New Roman",8) above in my code, After changing the font you showed everything lined right up. Any idea why?

Comment: Times New Roman does not appear to be a fixed with font. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces