# Concatenation of variable length strings with proper spacing

Tags: vb.net

So what I've done is manually insert space between the variables. Although it works, but if the variables is a bit long, it would move to the right. Here are the coding that I've done.

```
lstOutput.Items.Add("Items                                         Quantity                                         Prices")
lstOutput.Items.Add("Pizza Slices                                   " & quanPizza & "                                             " & FormatCurrency(pricePizza, 2))
lstOutput.Items.Add("Fries                                               " & quanFries & "                                             " & FormatCurrency(priceFries, 2))
lstOutput.Items.Add("Soft Drinks                                    " & quanSoftDrinks & "                                             " & FormatCurrency(priceSoftDrinks, 2))
lstOutput.Items.Add("")
lstOutput.Items.Add("Total                                                                                                " & FormatCurrency(totalPrice, 2))
```

[image]

Here is when the variable is a bit long.

[image]

How can i make it stay as if it is in a column?

Comment: Would you consider using a ListView or DataGridView?

Comment: The only way to align text in columns in a ListBox that uses a proportional Font, is to set the physical Tabs positions, using the [ListBox.CustomTabOffsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.customtaboffsets) (measured considering the *average length* of the parts, you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829552/7444103)). You probably don't want that. As suggested, use a ListView: no calculations, no weird padding, no hassles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) to format your strings as expected. Use this like below :

```
lstOutput.Items.Add("Items".PadRight(30) & "Quantity".PadRight(30) & "Prices".PadRight(30))
lstOutput.Items.Add("Pizza Slices".PadRight(30) & quanPizza.PadRight(30) & FormatCurrency(pricePizza, 2).ToString().PadRight(30))
```

Here is an [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmGrnO) for you.